# React-Native Error: Element type is invalid(). Check the render method of `Details`

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-navigation

Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `Details`.

Below i am attaching the code.I have double checked everything still it is giving error.I dont know what is the problem in rendering Details.js

This is App.js code.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';

import HomeScreen from './Home';
import DashboardScreen from './Dashboard'
import DetailsScreen from './Details';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

const MyStack = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Details" component={DetailsScreen}/>
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Home"
          component={HomeScreen}
          options={{ title: 'Welcome' }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen name="Dashboard" component={DashboardScreen} />
        
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}; 

export default MyStack
```

This is Details.js code below.

```
import React from "react";
import { Text,View} from "react-native-paper";

const Details = () => {
    return(
        <View style = {{flex: 1,justifyContent:'center',alignItems:'center'}}>
            <Text>
                Enter Details Here
            </Text>
        </View>
    )
}
export default Details;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please remember that Stack Overflow is not your favourite JavaScript forum, but rather a question and answer site for all programming related questions. Thus, please always include the tag of the language you are programming in, that way other users familiar with that language can more easily find your question. Take the [tour] and read up on [ask] to get more information on how this site works, then [edit] the question with the relevant tags.

Answer (score 0):

In your Details.js change

```
import { Text,View} from "react-native-paper";
```

to

```
import { Text, View} from "react-native";
```